# Can I check if a value is only pushed if a certain field value is not filled already?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to make a Meteor app to let users push a value to the database. It works ok, but there a small issue. As soon a certain user has pushed his information, i don't want to let the same user create another entry. Or this must be blocked, or the value the user is pushing must be overwritten for the value he is posting the second time. Now I get multiple entry's of the same user.

Here is my code. Hope you can help me here. Thanks in advance.

```
        Estimations.update(userstory._id, {
            $addToSet: {
                estimations: [
                    {name: Meteor.user().username, estimation: this.value}
                ]
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can check collection for the existance the name field with current name and then update or insert value. I mean you need to write if condition on the back-end.

Answer (score 2):

From the [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)

> The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is
>   already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array.

Since your array elements are *objects* the *value* is the entire object, not just the username key. This means a single user can create multiple `name, estimation` pairs as long as the `estimation` value is different.

What you can do is remove any value for the user first, then reinsert:

```
var username = Meteor.user().username;

Estimations.update({ userstory._id },
  { $pull: { estimations: { name: username }}}); // if it doesn't exist this will no-op

Estimations.update({userstory._id },
  { $push: { estimations: { name: username, estimation: this.value }}});
```

By way of commentary, you've got a collection called `Estimations` that contains an array called `estimations` that contains objects with keys `estimation`. This might confuse future developers on the project ;) Also if your `Estimations` collection is 1:1 with `UserStory`s then perhaps the array could just be a key inside the `UserStory` document?